# Is it possible to create a new Block from a VectorView of a 3D model?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

Assume I have a 3D model imported from a step file. I have

- `Design design1` to work with a 3D imported model.
- `Drawing drawing` where I create my 2D `VectorView topView`
- `Design design2` where I work on my actual design

I would like to create a Block from this `topView` to use in `Design design2` and if I change the model in `design1` and/or create another `VectorView` on `drawing` does not impact anything on `design2`. The current workaround is to save the `topView` as a 2D CAD then import it back.

My code to read the 3D step file and place it to `design1`

```
var rf = new ReadSTEP(@"C:\\Sample3DModel.stp");

rf.DoWork();

rf.AddToScene(design1)
```

My code to create a vector view `viewType.Top`

```
            drawing.Sheets.Clear();

            //Empty sheet
            var sheet1 = new Sheet(linearUnitsType.Millimeters, 100, 100, "Sheet 1");

            var topView = new VectorView(80, 80, viewType.Top, sheet1.Scale, "Top");

            topView.HiddenSegments = false;

            topView.Selectable = false;

            sheet1.Entities.Add(topView);

            drawing.Sheets.Add(sheet1);

            drawing.Rebuild(design1);

            drawing.ActiveSheet = sheet1;

            drawing.Invalidate();
```

I tried to collect Entities from topView but error `var entities =  topView.GetEntities(new BlockKeyedCollection()); error: 'A Block with name Top does not exist.'`

Comment: Did you clone all the entities of `Top` VectorView?

Comment: @abenci - how can I get the list of the entities underlined from VectorView? I only see a method from `VectorView.GetEntities` but I do not know how to pass the `BlockKeyedCollection`

Comment: Please try `design1.CopyTo(design2)` and you'll get an exact (deep) copy of what you have on design1.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  I think it is acceptable but I still prefer a way to change the `VectorView` to `Block` so it can be used as a reference\reused on the same design. Again, thank very much for the help.

Comment: This makes no sense to me, `VectorView` is a `BlockReference`, not a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `design1.CopyTo(design2)` and you'll get an exact -deep- copy of what you have on `design1` control.